# How to set up my native node module if it is imported by my host project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsconfig

I am developing 2 projects in TypeScript. First, a native node module called `my-node-module`. It is imported by my host project called `host-project`.

[image]

### package.json of `host-project`

```
"my-node-module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:foo/my-node-module"
```

`my-node-module` is written in TypeScript. I want to import it within my host project.

## Question 1

The main entry in the package.json of `my-node-module` is `js/index.js`. This file is created if I call `npm run tsc` in the root of `my-node-module`.

Can I directly import the project (`src/index.ts`) file via `import myModule from 'my-node-module'` or is the transpile step really necessary?

## Question 2

If the question above is answered with yes, how would I ensure that `npm i` on the host project also executes the required transpile steps for my dependency module `my-node-module`?

Comment: Is there a reason not to build your npm project and push the build code to the repo as well ?

Comment: There is no reason, I was just wondering if this is the right approach. How would I avoid source and build files being out of sync? Is a git hook to build/compile before pushing a standard practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use similar approach in one of my commercial project. I have some common code used by all,

1. React JS frontend
2. React Native frontend
3. Express js based graphql server

Then there's another package which has UI components ready to import in React JS web and React Native mobile projects.

All of these projects are install as npm packages and hosted in remote git repos ( In my case, they are on remote Bitbucket repositories  )

For example, I have following configuration for my shared logic project.

package @myorg/common-logics

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/common-logics",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "types": "./build/index.d.ts",
  "private": true,
  "files": [
    "build/**/*"
  ],
  "author": "Dilshan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf build",
    "build": "yarn run clean && tsc",
    "test": "npx ts-node src/test/data.ts",
    "version-upgrade": "yarn version patch",
    "changelog": "standard-version"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.177",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "standard-version": "^9.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    
  },
  "repository": {}
```

Previously I manually built this project by running `yarn build` because I was the only one works on this shared package. You can also use [Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) or a pipeline as well.

If I had to push this to a npm registry, i would have built the code in a pipeline.

---

This worked until I had to manage multiple npm packages. It was getting harder to keep track all of them so Here I used https://nx.dev/ to manage all of my npm packages. Then I created separate repositories ( Because I didn't used a NPM registry ) just to hold the build code of each packages in NX mono repo.

So all I do is, do my development in NX mono repo and then push it to the repository. Then in a pipeline I build the libraries in NX project and push them to the read only repositories that just hold the latest build code of the source code.

I can say it works & currently the production system uses these shared libraries and I have been working with these custom shared libraries over 6 - 7 months now. I never had any issues unless this one [problem](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10627) with NX. Also never had a source code - build code sync issue so far.

If you cannot setup CI/CD pipelines, I guess you can do the same thing in your local machine with Husky and custom shell script to build and copy build code to readonly repos.

Comment: That's a great idea. So I have basically two repos. One for TS, and one that only contains the build code. Or I could even merge them and trigger the CI only if the push/update didn't come from the CI itself.

Comment: If you only have one npm project, you can keep both build and source code in same project as well. As you can see in my package.json, I have included build files and pointed the index to build/index.js

Answer (score -1):

I normally use a `SharedModule` for using common modules across multiple projects.

you can create a shared module that has all these modules and components. Import them into a shared module and import this shared module into all feature modules. This will save imports and a lot of coding lines.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { NewItemDirective } from './new-item.directive';
import { OrdersPipe } from './orders.pipe';

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe ],
 exports:      [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe,
                 CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Notice the following:

1. It imports the `CommonModule` because the module's component needs common directives
2. It declares and exports the utility pipe, directive, and component classes
3. It re-exports the `CommonModule` and `FormsModule`

By re-exporting `CommonModule` and `FormsModule`, any other module that imports this `SharedModule`, gets access to directives like `NgIf` and `NgFor` from `CommonModule` and can bind to component properties with `[(ngModel)]`, a directive in the `FormsModule`.

Even though the components declared by `SharedModule` might not bind with `[(ngModel)]` and there may be no need for `SharedModule` to import `FormsModule`, `SharedModule` can still export `FormsModule` without listing it among its imports. This way, you can give other modules access to `FormsModule` without having to import it directly into the `@NgModule` decorator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer covers Angular code, I am building a pure node js project, Angular isn't involved.

Comment: How about Publishing a library to npm for `my-node-module` and then installing the library in to `host-module`

Comment: We cannot host code outside of GitHub, even when npm is part of MS now.